# conversion of list of list of tuples to dict not working as expected

Tags: python, list, dictionary, tuples, valueerror

I am trying to create the `dict` for this list of lists contains tuples. The purpose is to filter the needed tuples into the final list.

What I have tried so far:

```
dict_1 = dict()
for val,sim in result:
    dict_1.setdefault(val, [])


print(result)
```

It works fine when I look into result and unpack two values `(val,sim)`. But every time it is not the same case i will get, there could be multiple values to unpack and then it gives this error:

```
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2).
```

How can make the above loop `for val,sim in result:` flexible?

This is the input format:

```
[[(1.0, 2481), (0.125, 5)], [(1.0, 2481), (0.10526315789473684, 1), (0.0, 5), (0.0, 4), (0.0, 3), (0.0, 2)], [(1.0, 2481), (0.11764705882352941, 2), (0.0, 5), (0.0, 4), (0.0, 3), (0.0, 1)], [(1.0, 2481), (0.13333333333333333, 3), (0.0, 5), (0.0, 4), (0.0, 2), (0.0, 1)], [(1.0, 2481), (0.1, 4), (0.0, 5), (0.0, 3), (0.0, 2), (0.0, 1)]]
```

My ultimate goal is to make the dict first and then start filtering the tuples i am only interested in the tuples `[(value,sim), (value,sim)]` which have a specific value `sim` but before doing that I am stuck in above part.

Desired output:

```
[(1.0, 2481), (0.125, 5), (0.10526315789473684, 1),(0.11764705882352941, 2), (0.13333333333333333, 3), (0.1, 4)]
```

I am just a beginner. I understand this might not be the correct way to ask question. But any kind of little guidance in right direction would be appreciated!

Comment: But you're not creating a `dict`? Your approach can't work with a single loop because it's clear that you have a _nested_ structure that will require at least 2 loops (even if the loop itself is hidden in some library :P )

Comment: how did you arrive at the result? may be you wouldn't need a dictionary in between.

Comment: for i in range (len(m)):
        PA, AP, size_m2 = matrixNew(read_PA_au(au, m[i-1]))
        APA = (AP * PA).todense()
        result.append(fuc2(au, APA, size_m2,k))
        
        
    dict_1 = dict()
    for val,sim in result:
        dict_1.setdefault(val, [])

    
    print(result)

Comment: This is the result i get [[(1.0, 2481), (0.1, 4)], [(1.0, 2481), (0.10526315789473684, 1)], [(1.0, 2481), (0.11764705882352941, 2)], [(1.0, 2481), (0.13333333333333333, 3)]]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try nested slicing:

```
a = [[(1.0, 2481), (0.125, 5)], 
     [(1.0, 2481), (0.10526315789473684, 1), (0.0, 5), (0.0, 4), (0.0, 3), (0.0, 2)], 
     [(1.0, 2481), (0.11764705882352941, 2), (0.0, 5), (0.0, 4), (0.0, 3), (0.0, 1)], 
     [(1.0, 2481), (0.13333333333333333, 3), (0.0, 5), (0.0, 4), (0.0, 2), (0.0, 1)], 
     [(1.0, 2481), (0.1, 4), (0.0, 5), (0.0, 3), (0.0, 2), (0.0, 1)]]

b = [a[0][0]] + [i[1] for i in a]

print(b)
```

Output:

```
[(1.0, 2481), 
 (0.125, 5), 
 (0.10526315789473684, 1), 
 (0.11764705882352941, 2), 
 (0.13333333333333333, 3), 
 (0.1, 4)]
```

Comment: It actually helped! what if i only want a unique list of tuples a the end. I tried to store the final result into set but it changed the format of final output.
finalresult = [result[0][0]] + [i[1] for i in result[:k]]

    final = set(itertools.chain.from_iterable(finalresult))
    print(final)


it produced this: 

{0.0, 1.0, 0.10526315789473684, 0.11764705882352941, 2, 0.13333333333333333, 3, 0.1, 4, 0.125, 5, 12, 2481}

Comment: finalresult = list(dict.fromkeys(result)) it worked by converting back to list! and it also preserved the order.

Comment: I am slicing the list from opposite direction, as a requirement and i get TypeError: bad operand type for unary -: 'list' Can you help with that what could be the issue? This is the statement: finalresult = [result[0][0]] + [[i[-j] for j in result[:k]] for i in result[:k]]

Comment: @Sniper Well, is `j` an integer? If not, then `-j`  wouldn't work, right?

Comment: the value at -j index is not an integer, its a tuple. I am i am trying to access the value at -j index in my list. Starting from tail of the list to head.

Comment: I am curious why this statement doesn't work. In every nested list i want -1,-2,-3 element of the list. This also gives an error finalresult = [result[0][0]] + [i[-i] for i in result[:k]]

Comment: @Sniper you can use `enumerate`. Observe: `for index, value in enumerate([4, 5, 2]): print(index, value)`.